# How to compare current date with mysql date?

Tags: php, mysql

i am tried to display the current birthday by matching the current date .
Mysql date format was 16 September 1990, So i  trimmed the year from the current date and echoed 16 Sep, Now how to echo ,if the current date is equal to the date in the row . I tried the below method ,it was an error .

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata" );
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone($timezone );
$date2= $date->format( 'd M' );
$date4=date('d M', strtotime($date2));


<?php $sel = $db->query("select * from mov_birthday where date('d M', strtotime(dateofb)) == '$date4' order by dateofb"); 

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel)){

echo ($row['name']); } ?>
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `like`:

```
// this will select every date that starts with date('d M') - day Month
$timezone = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata" );
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone($timezone);
$dateFormat = $date->format( 'd F' );
$sel = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `mov_birthday` where `dateofb` LIKE '".$dateFormat."%' ORDER BY `dateofb`");
while($row = $sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```